# Polymer 1.x: How to print all the properties of a Polymer element?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, custom-element

How do I print to the console all the properties of an element I have imported into a custom element.

For example, I have a custom element `my-el` and in that element, I have imported a `firebase-document` element. I want to know the current state of the model for the `firebase-document` element by observing the value of all the properties of the `firebase-document` at a particular point in time.

my-el.html

```
<firebase-document id="document"
                   app-name="my-app"
                   data="{{data}}">
</firebase-document>
...
foo: function() {
  ...
  var doc = this.$.document;
  // Neither of the following "works" (see below for definition)
  console.log('doc', doc);
  console.log('doc.properties', doc.properties);
}
```

By *works*, I mean it does not produce the desired behavior of printing an object to the console. The object being [all the properties](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/polymerfire?active=firebase-document) of the `doc` object.

Comment: Did you try `console.dir( doc )`?

Comment: @Supersharp: That works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `console.dir()`, but you can also use the `%o` substitution string in a standard `console.log()` call:

```
console.log( 'doc=%o', doc );
```

The [list of substition strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Using_string_substitutions) is avaiable on MDN's website.

Answer (score 1):

Summary from comments:

Use

```
console.dir( doc );
```